# jQuery Change the Dropdown values based on other dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am using following Jscript to show **24 hours format** of time **FromTime** and **ToTime**

Almost it is working fine, but have some issues as it is not appending all the values from first dropdown and some times for some value i select in first dropdown the sort order or the immd time is not on the top

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<select id="one">
     <option value="1">1:00</option>
    <option value="2">1:30</option>
    <option value="3">2:00</option>
    <option value="4">2:30</option>
    <option value="5">3:00</option>
    <option value="6">3:30</option>
    <option value="7">4:00</option>
    <option value="8">4:30</option>
    <option value="9">5:00</option>
    <option value="10">5:30</option>
    <option value="11">6:00</option>
    <option value="12">6:30</option>
    <option value="13">7:00</option>
    <option value="14">7:30</option>
    <option value="15">8:00</option>
    <option value="16">8:30</option>
    <option value="17">9:00</option>
    <option value="18">9:30</option>
    <option value="19">10:00</option>
    <option value="20">10:30</option>
    <option value="21">11:00</option>
    <option value="22">11:30</option>
    <option value="23">12:00</option>
    <option value="24">12:30</option>
    <option value="25">13:00</option>
    <option value="26">13:30</option>
    <option value="27">14:00</option>
    <option value="28">14:30</option>
    <option value="29">15:00</option>
    <option value="30">15:30</option>
    <option value="31">16:00</option>
    <option value="32">16:30</option>
    <option value="33">17:00</option>
    <option value="34">17:30</option>
    <option value="35">18:00</option>
    <option value="36">18:30</option>
    <option value="37">19:00</option>
    <option value="38">19:30</option>
    <option value="39">20:00</option>
    <option value="40">20:30</option>
    <option value="41">21:00</option>
    <option value="42">21:30</option>
    <option value="43">22:00</option>
    <option value="44">22:30</option>
    <option value="45">23:00</option>
    <option value="46">23:30</option>
    <option value="47">00:00</option>
    <option value="48">00:30</option>

  </select>

    <select id="two"></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#one").change(function (e) {
                $("#two").empty();

                var options = 
                $("#one option").filter(function(e){
                    return $(this).attr("value") > $("#one option:selected").val();
                }).clone();

                $("#two").append(options);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are being compared as strings, simply parse them to int and then compare:

```
return parseInt($(this).attr("value"),10) > parseInt($("#one option:selected").val(),10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XMq2T/1/